# Can't access Local Users made in Powershell 4.0?

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, scripting

Even after rebooting I can't find the "Test" user in the users folder or anywhere else for that matter. However, when I try repeating the steps using the same variables, Powershell tells me that the "Test" user account already exists.

For my job at an IT firm, I have to write a script using Powershell that creates a new local user among other actions. I followed the tutorial here http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/ and entered the following commands-

```
$cn = [ADSI]"WinNT://Inquisition"

$user = $cn.Create("User","Test")

$user.SetPassword("P@ssword!")

$user.setinfo()

$user.description = "TestUser"

$user.SetInfo()
```

I'm new to Powershell, and starting to get a headache. Any Ideas?

Comment: You say you *can't find them in the users folder* - are you looking in `c:\users`? That's not where users are, that's where the profile folders of *users who have logged in* are. Local accounts are in `Start -> Run -> lusrmgr.msc`

Comment: Yes, I was looking in the Users folder, thankyou. The page that came up when I ran lusrmgr.msc gave a red error and informed me that "This snapin may not be used with this edition of windows 8.1" and deferred me to User Accounts in the Control Panel, where of course the account I created doesn't show up.

Comment: Ah. What if you run Command Prompt, and type `net user` ?

Comment: Both the test names I used came up, so I guess they do exist. One more question if it isn't too much trouble, how do I change the settings in windows so that these users are actually visible on the log in screen? Or at least to where you type in the username and password instead of clicking on an account?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. And from a quick look around, it doesn't look like it's made easy - e.g. this says there's one registry key which can do it, but Windows resets it every time you reboot - http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/force-windows-8-to-show-all-user-accounts-on-the-sign-on-screen/

Comment: Thanks for looking around for me. I use 8.1 on my PC, but thankfully my firm uses windows 7. Hopefully it won't be a problem on their network. I'm wrapping up this script, there's just a couple more tasks I need to figure out. I'll post again if I run into any blocking issues.

Comment: Creating a user account does not automatically create a user's profile folder. That only occurs when the user first logs in on that computer.

Comment: The error message "This snapin may not be used with this edition of windows 8.1" means that you're running a non pro or enterprise edition of Windows. To be honest : your boss should come up with decent corporate versions of Windows to test stuff like this (every customer that I support is using at least a pro edition, otherwise we won't support them, we like to make money on customers and not lose money because we can't automate)

Comment: Yeah I figured that was what the error message meant, I should probably upgrade my own version of windows. Like I said above, I use 8.1 on my Personal Computer, but my firm uses Windows 7; I believe pro.   @Bob M, Do you have any Idea how I can log in an account that doesn't yet have a profile on 8.1?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Maybe give the new account RDP rights and connect from another computer ? :-) but I'm not sure on non-Pro versions of Windows you can use RDP ...

Comment: Sharing a folder and then doing a `net use` on it with the *ghost* account credentials *did* create the `C:\Users\TestUser` profile folder. But still no clue about logging in with this account. I'll try RDP now : ).

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll look into the process to see if it will solve my problem

Comment: @sodawillow Update- I downloaded a file located here [http://www.eightforums.com](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/19412-sign-user-name-password-windows-8-a.html) which made a registry change allowing me to type in the username and password upon signing in on Windows 8.1. They also offer a recovery file to change things back to normal if the user so chooses. Problem resolved.